# Quasi-coherent sheaves on affinoid space

Tags: sheaf-theory, rigid-analytic-geometry

From Conrad's [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/aws.pdf) on rigid geometry:

> More specifically, Gabber has given an example of a sheaf of modules $F$ on the closed unit disk $B^1$ such that $F$ is locally a direct limit of coherent sheaves but with nonzero degree-1 sheaf cohomology, so
> $F$ cannot be expressed as a direct limit of coherent sheaves over the entire affinoid space...

What is this example due to Gabber? Is there a reference describing it?

Comment: FWIW, the user appears to have been part of a group of accounts controlled by the same individual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Example 2.1.6 in [this](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/amplepaperfinal.pdf) paper.